# GlusterFS storage for docker images

Tags: docker, docker-image, glusterfs

I have a docker swarm with 10 docker worker nodes and i'm experiencing issues with docker images storage (in thin pool). It keeps getting full as i got rather small disks (30GB-60GB).
The error:

```
Thin Pool has 7330 free data blocks which is less than minimum required 8455 free data blocks. Create more free space in thin pool or use dm.min_free_space option to change behavior
```

Because of that, cleaning strategy has to be aggressive, meaning deleting all images three times a day. This aggressive cleaning strategy results in broken pulls ( when cleaning happens at the same time when someone is pulling an image) and that developers cannot use cached images - instead they need to download the images that just got deleted by cleaning mechanism.

However, there is an option to use GlusterFs storage and i want to mount glusterFS volumes to each docker node and use them to create thin pool for docker images and /var/lib/docker. 
I'm looking for guide how to do that exactly. Have anyone tried that?

P.S. I made my research about shared storage for docker images between multiple docker nodes and it seems its not possible, as stated [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15887). However mounting separate volumes to each docker node should be possible.